# What sins are not forgiven because of lack of guidance?

Tags: sin, tawba

I am looking for scholarly discussions or classifications for types of sins that are not forgiven due to lack of guidance.

Obviously, the most well-known sin that is forgiven because there was no guidance to the person is disbelief. But, I assume things like missing obligatory prayers and drinking alcohol are also in this category since it is not possible to know their sinfulness without revelation.

There are other sins, though, that clearly are not forgiven for lack of revelation such as stealing, murder, lying, adultery or even just physical assault.

So, is there any way of distinguishing between the two used by scholars?

Comment: It appears that you're conflating forgiveness of sins with punishment of crimes. They are not the same.

Comment: @goldPseudo . No, I realize the difference. For example, lying is a sin that does not need guidance to know it is bad, and it is not a punishable crime.